# What is Sitecore.Abstractions dll?

Tags: sitecore-api

I am getting error:

```
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly '**Sitecore.Abstractions**, 
  Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its 
  dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

at runtime, while trying to execute a Unit Test method. I did not find this dll anywhere. Anyone has any idea this particular DLL?

Regards,
Chandana

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting Ruud van Falier ([Sitecore.Abstractions.dll in Sitecore 7.5](https://www.partech.nl/nl/blog/2014/09/sitecore-abstractions-dll-in-sitecore-7-5)):

> Sitecore 7.5 ships with a new binary named Sitecore.Abstractions.dll
>   This offers you abstractions for some parts of the Sitecore API that are implemented as static classes in the kernel. Being static classes, there is no way to run unit tests on code that is depending on them without running from within a Sitecore application.
>
> If you ever tried unit testing in Sitecore, you will know that if you call Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MySettingKey"), for example, it will always be null.
>   Because the unit test does not actually load the Sitecore application, it will have no configuration in memory and thus no access to settings.

That dll should be in the `bin` folder of your web application.

Or you can download it from nuget: https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Abstractions

Comment: No, this DLL was not present. We can get it via Sitecore nuget package and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and Sitecore.Abstractions dll was not present in the bin. We can add Sitecore nuget source[image: Sitecore nuget package source]

And install it from there